# Add Lib Content to Main Section TYPO3 6.2 Typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

can someone help me adding a lib to the main section of the page via typoscript

TS:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 314]
includeLibs.voucher = fileadmin/php/shop_init.php
lib.phpscript = USER
lib.phpscript.userFunc = voucher->init
[global]
```

Template:

```
<div class="main-section">
        <f:render section="Main" />

       <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.phpscript" />  
    </div>
```

Now the content is showing after the Main section but i need it in the main section :/

What is the ts code for this??

THX in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.phpscript" />
```

in a template between the tags

```
<f:section name="main"></f:section>
```

You can find the templates in the folder:

```
your_extension\Resources\Private\Templates\
```